# install flash debugger on linux for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

i am trying to install flash debugger on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS for Chrome.

i downloaded from https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html
the version Download the Flash Player Plugin content debugger (64-bit) - PPAPI..

I then deleted the folder /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin and restarted chrome to check if it warns me that there is no flash installed on this page https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

but it says i still have flash installed version xxxx..xxx

so where is flash for chrome located?

i need to place the debug version of flash there. even after replacing the contents of the above folder with the contents of the downloaded file, i still do not see the debug version of flash

**EDIT**

thanks to Joshs comment I now know it is in /.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/28.0.0.137, but on replacing the contents with the debug version (including manifest), I am now displayed the flash version of 24.0.0 instead of the debugger version

How do I enable/install the debug version of flash?

Comment: `chrome://version/` gives the location of flash plugin

Comment: thanks that helps in my first step

Comment: still no one! For firefox it was simple, the location was /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer